# How to get image path in text format using PHP?

Tags: php

How to get image path in text format using PHP?

I have text format like this:

```
<p><span style="\&quot;background-color:" rgb(255,="" 255,="" 0);="" font-weight:="" bold;="" font-style:="" italic;="" text-decoration:="" underline;\"="">TEST</span>&nbsp;<img src="\&quot;https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:" 544px;\"="">&nbsp;<span style="\&quot;font-style:" italic;\"="">TEST<img src="\&quot;https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:" 200px;\"=""></span><br></p>
```

My code is:

```
<?php
$str='<p><span style="\&quot;background-color:" rgb(255,="" 255,="" 0);="" font-weight:="" bold;="" font-style:="" italic;="" text-decoration:="" underline;\"="">TEST</span>&nbsp;<img src="\&quot;https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:" 544px;\"="">&nbsp;<span style="\&quot;font-style:" italic;\"="">TEST<img src="\&quot;https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:" 200px;\"=""></span><br></p>';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTML( $str );
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//img');
$images=array();
foreach( $col as $img ) $images[]=$img->getAttribute('src');
echo $images[0];
?>
```

When I test my code, it shows:

```
\"https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\"
```

I want to know how to change my code to show:

```
https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

Comment: Parts of that text has been run through `addslashes()` and then `htmlentities()`.

Comment: In other words: why is that piece of HTML completely garbled and somewhere between not-what-you-think-it-is and outright invalid?

Answer (score 0):

echo substr($images[0],2,strlen($images[0])-5);
If I am not wrong if 
`$images[0] =\"https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\"`

Then substr function will take $images[0] string to be sliced, it will start from index 2 and get strlen($images[0])-5 pieces of char which is strlen($images[0]) is the size of the string - 5 then it will produce the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can should use `stripslashes` to remove the and if you want html entities in their applicable characters, use `html_entity_decode`.

So, your echo should look something like:

```
echo stripslashes(html_entity_decode($images[0]));
```

OR

```
echo stripslashes($images[0]);
```

depending upon if you want to convert html entities as well.